# Showing the set $\{x: x = 2^{-k} \ k\in \mathbb{N}\ \text{or}\ x = 0 \}$ is open, closed, or neither - solution feedback

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus, elementary-set-theory

This question comes from *Shifrin's  Multivariable Mathermatics - Sec 2.2 - 1(b)*, it asks:
Show that the set  $B = \{x: x = 2^{-k} \ k\in \mathbb{N}\ \text{or}\ x = 0 \}$ is open, closed, or neither and prove your answer.

I've come to the conclusion that the set is closed and I wanted some assistance on tightening up my solution.

**Solution**

The tools I have up to this point to show that a set is closed are:

i) show all convergent sequences in the set converge to a point in the set.

ii) Show that the complement of the set is open.

I chose to approach this problem using (ii), but I do have a question about how I could use (i) I'll ask at the end.

So first I have to figure out what it means to be in $C = \mathbb{R} - B$. To me this meant $\mathbb{R} - B = \{x: x \neq 2^{-k}\ \text{and} x \neq 0\}$. To build off of this idea I drew a picture of the number line with the points belonging to $B$ and observed how the points of $C$ would have to be to satisfy my argument. So after some fiddling around I defined the points of $C$ as follows:

$$C = \mathbb{R} - B = \{y: y = x\pm \delta\ \text{depending on which side of an $x$ from $B$ that the point $y$ is in relation to}\}$$.

So how do I choose my $\delta$? So keep in mind that each $x \in B$ is actually a function of a particular $k$, so with this in mind I defined $\delta = \min(|2^{-k}-y|, |2^{-(k+1)}-y|)$. In this set up it means I'm taking a $\delta$ that will take into consideration the possibility of having an open ball over a value $x \in B$ which we don't want.

So with this setup I now need to show $C$ is open. Define a point $z \in C$ as $z = x \pm \frac{\delta}{2}$.

By this definition we see that $z \in B(y, \delta)$. It's here where I'm having trouble completing the proof. So to show the ball is open is dependent on where my $y$ value is, so for a concrete argument let's suppose that $y < 2^{-k}$. To show  $B(y, \delta) \subset C$ means I have to show for all $z \in B(y, \delta)$ that:

$$|z - y| < |2^{-k} - y| \\
\Rightarrow\ |z - y| < 2^{-k} - y\ \text{(since assuming $y < 2^{-k}$ case)}$$

I'm having trouble arriving at the conclusion...What I envision happening after some algebra is:

$$2^{-(k+1)} < z < 2^{-k}$$

Which would then give me my open ball.

So I have two questions:

1. My idea seems to be leading me in the right direction, but needs some fine-tuning. What do I need to do to tighten it up?
2. With regards to the other way of showing closed. In this set it seems like the only sequence is the set itself since the $x = 2^{-k}$ and that will converge to $0$, but can I actually say that this is true? Couldn't there be some rare sequences that I have not found that are in the set, but since I have not explicitly stated all convergent sequences then I can't use the definition of closed explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, by either of the two techniques you described you could arrive to the conclusion (see that $2^{-k}$ aproaches $0$ when $k$ goes to infnity) but for a more topological aproach I would sugest you try to write the compliment as the union of disjoint open intervals.

Comment: I'm kind of restricted as in what I could use. I was just looking at the exercises further down and one of them asks to prove the union of open intervals is open, so I can't technically use the concept. But even if I could, it would still rest on me establishing one open interval first and I guess that would follow from the idea I have above.  As for the sequence $2^{-k}$ approaching $0$, how do I know that's the only sequence in the set? I'm asking this more so abstractly so I have an idea to approach this idea in the future.

Comment: If a point belongs to the union of open sets then it belongs to one open set so there is an open interval contained in that one set ergo in the union of the open sets. The compliment of that set is $$(-\infty, 0)\cup\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty(2^{-(n+1)},2^{-n})\cup(1,\infty)$$

Comment: I don't dispute this being the case, but as of now I can't use the idea of unions of open sets because I haven't "proven" it yet in the course of the text. So I have to use the ideas I have at my disposal thus far. I don't mean to make it more complicated than it has to be, apologies.

Comment: Okay no worries. Then lets take a point $y$, if $y>1$ then there is a point $x=y-\varepsilon$ between $1$ and $y$ so $(y-\varepsilon,y+\varepsilon)$ is contained in the compliment because all the points in $B$ are less or equal than $1$, the sabe can be done for $y<0$. Now if $0<y<1$ then there exists $k$ such that $2^{-(k+1)}<y<2^{-k}$ (notice since 2^{-k} is decreasing there isn’t $k_0$ such that $2^{-(k+1)}<2^{-k_0}<2^{-k}$) so we can find $x_0=y-\varepsilon_0$ between $2^{-(k+1)}$ and $y$, and $x_1=y+\varepsilon_1$, so take $\varepsilon$ as the minimum of $\varepsilon_0,\varepsilon_1$

Comment: And $(y-\varepsilon,y+\varepsilon)$ will be contained in the compliment. (No space left on the previous comment)

Comment: I hope I was clear, if you still have doubts feel free to ask

Comment: Also I forgot to add that $x_1=y+\varepsilon_1$ is between $y$ and $2^{-k}$.

Comment: You were perfectly clear. Thanks for your help.